# How to use JQuery DateTime Picker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetime, datetimepicker

I am a beginner programmer and I'm trying to make a web page that displays a JQuery Inline Date and Time Picker. As I was researching, I found this documentation: [DateTimePicker](http://xdsoft.net/jqplugins/datetimepicker/). I followed the steps of first importing the JS and CSS files (after the closing body tag) using these tags:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

Following those tags, I called on my `<input>` from my **Home.html** file with the id of `datetimepicker`. Then using that id, I copied the code from the tutorial that creates the Inline DateTime Picker Calendar, like so:

```
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
     inline:true
  });
```

So my **Home.html** file looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
   <meta charset="utf-8">

   <title>Home</title>
   <!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/css/materialize.min.css">

   <!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.97.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>

   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery.datetimepicker.css"/>
   <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

 </head>
 <body>
     <h3>Inline DateTimePicker</h3>
     <input type="text" id="datetimepicker"/><input type="button" onclick="$('#datetimepicker3').datetimepicker({value:'2011/12/11 12:00'})" value="set inline value 2011/12/11 12:00"/><br><br>
 </body>
 <!-- CALLS JQUERY LIBRARY FOR DATE AND TIME PICKER -->
 <!-- this should go after your </body> -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >
  <script src="./jquery.js"></script>
  <script src="./jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
  <script>
      $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
        inline:true
      });
  </script>
</html>
```

However, when I run this code, I get an error that says:

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating '$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    inline:true
  })')
```

This is what is displaying:
[image: This is what is displaying]

This is what I want to display:

[image]

How can I get an Inline calendar to display on my **Home.html** page?

Comment: You have referenced jquery twice

Comment: I am using Google Maps API and if I delete the first one I referenced, the map doesn't load. If I delete the second one, the calendar still does not load.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include jquery-ui.js

Comment: I did download it and now I've referenced it. I placed the JS and CSS files into the respective folders in my public directory. However, the calendar is still not displaying.

Answer (score 1):

Put

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery.datetimepicker.css"/ >    
<script src="./jquery.datetimepicker.js"></script>
```

between your `<head></head>` tags and remove

```
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same sort of issue , If download the the source code from the [XDSoft site](https://github.com/xdan/datetimepicker/archive/master.zip)

there is build folder , try using **jquery.datetimepicker.full.js** file from build folder .

Answer (score 0):

Do not confuse between jQuery versions. You first referenced jQuery here:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

And then you are doing it here:

```
<script src="./jquery.js"></script>
```

Please remove one. As the newer jQuery will be active and it doesn't have the plugin registered.

Comment: If I remove the first one, the rest of my program does not function as I am using a Google Maps API. If I delete the second one (<script src="./jquery.js"></script>) then the calendar still does not display. I'm only getting an input field.