# Problem changing format in django project

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a problem with frontend development.
Let me bring you up to date:
I have a table on the site that imports data from the database, I need this data to be changed by an operator, I created a Change button after which a popup appears, in the Date field I was able to change the format and screw the date selection through the calendar, but I changed the format in the Estimated time field It doesn’t work in any way, it always says Invalid date.I'm new to programming, so don't judge too harshly :) Thanks for your time
Here's the code:

```
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {% for order in orders %}
      <tr>
        <td>{{ order.status }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.date|date:"Y-m-d"}}</td>
        <td>{{ order.preferred_time|time:"H:i" }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.cargo_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.cargo_quantity }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.order_number }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.cargo_weight }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.driver_name }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.vehicle_license_plate }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.vehicle_type }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.shipper }}</td>
        <td>{{ order.transport_company_name }}</td>
        <td>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="modal" data-bs-target="#editOrderModal"
            onclick="openEditModal('{{ order.id }}', '{{ order.status }}', '{{ order.date }}', '{{ order.preferred_time }}', '{{ order.cargo_type }}', '{{ order.cargo_quantity }}', '{{ order.order_number }}', '{{ order.cargo_weight }}', '{{ order.driver_name }}', '{{ order.vehicle_license_plate }}', '{{ order.vehicle_type }}', '{{ order.shipper }}', '{{ order.transport_company_name }}')">Edit</button>
        </td>
      </tr>
      {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="editOrderModal" data-bs-backdrop="static" data-bs-keyboard="false" tabindex="-1"
  aria-labelledby="editOrderModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h1 class="modal-title fs-5" id="editOrderModalLabel">Edit Order</h1>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <!-- Edit Order Form -->
        <form id="editOrderForm" method="post" action="{% url 'edit_order' %}">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <input type="hidden" name="editOrderId" id="editOrderId" value="">

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="editStatus" class="form-label">Status:</label>
            <input type="text" id="editStatus" name="editStatus" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="editDate" class="form-label">Date:</label>
            <input type="text" id="editDate" name="editDate" class="form-control datepicker">
          </div>

          <div class="mb-3">
            <label for="editPreferredTime" class="form-label">Preferred Time:</label>
            <input type="text" id="editPreferredTime" name="editPreferredTime" class="form-control">
          </div>

          <!-- Additional fields go here -->

          <!-- Buttons for saving changes and closing the modal -->
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save Changes</button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{% block script %}
<script>

  $('.datepicker').datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',  // Date format that matches Django
    autoclose: true,
  });

  function openEditModal(orderId, status, date, preferredTime, cargoType, cargoQuantity, orderNumber, cargoWeight, driverName, licensePlate, vehicleType, shipper, companyName) {
    document.getElementById('editOrderId').value = orderId;
    document.getElementById('editStatus').value = status;
    var formattedDate = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-CA', { year: 'numeric', month: '2-digit', day: '2-digit' });
    document.getElementById('editDate').value = formattedDate;
    document.getElementById('editPreferredTime').value = preferredTime;
    // Additional fields go here
  }
</script>
{% endblock script %}

{% endblock content %}
```

I looked for information on the forum and used ChatGPT, but even there I could not find information.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use JQuery DateTime Picker?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31967293/how-to-use-jquery-datetime-picker)